# Ambiguity in constructing multi-dimensional random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that I have:

- random variable $X$ which is distributed according to $f_X$ or  $X \sim f_X.$
- another random variable $Y$ which is distributed according to
  $f_Y$ or $Y \sim f_Y.$

Suppose now I want to construct a two-dimension vector $\begin{bmatrix} X\\ Y \end{bmatrix}$. **What is the distribution that this two-dimension random variable follow?**

I have seen two answers on this matter, the first is that $\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix} f_X \\ f_Y \end{bmatrix} = P$. In other words, we simply stacked their distribution and formed another one and then we call it $P$.

A second answer appears like this: $\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} \sim f_{X,Y}$, where $f_{X,Y}$ is a joint probability distribution.

My question is: what is the relationship between $\begin{bmatrix} f_X \\ f_Y \end{bmatrix} = P$ and $f_{X,Y}$? Are there any relationship? Which should be the correct version of the distribution of the two-dimension random vector?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent these are equivalent since $f_{X,Y}=f_Xf_Y$. But in general, the joint density is a map defined on $\mathbb R^2$ (as the notation $f_{X,Y}$ implies), as opposed to a vector of the marginal densities.

Comment: Perhaps where you saw the first answer, it was correct for the particular context where it occurred. (The second answer would also have been correct, but less informative.) We cannot know if the first answer was correct in its original context without seeing exactly what question it was actually answering.

Comment: @Math1000, can I encourage you to write that in an answer, so we can upvote it and so it can be marked as accepted and so the system will treat the question as answered?  Please don't write answers in the comments (even if they are short).